# PHP - How to subscribe user to MailerLite using API

Tags: php, api

On my website, people can register to become a member. Now I want them to be also immediately be subscribed to my MailerLite mailinglist. In the API documentation I have fount the following PHP example which should work:

```
$ML_Subscribers = new MailerLite\Subscribers('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
            $subscriber = array(
                'email' => $e,
                'name' => $f,
            );
            $subscriber = $ML_Subscribers->setId('xxxxxxxxxxx')->setAutoresponders(false)->add($subscriber);
```

The API url that's mentioned on their website is the following:

https://app.mailerlite.com/api/v1/subscribers/{list_id}/

I am unsure how to implement this URL in the script.. I have the above PHP code that should add a subscriber to the list, but should I also include the link in some way? I could use some help to make it work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When using the MailerLite SDK it is not required to post to any specific end point. There are wrappers within the functions that dictate the endpoint and method request type when sending data to their API.

The provided code below is all that is required:

```
$ML_Subscribers = new MailerLite\Subscribers( API_KEY );

$subscriber = array(
    'email' => $e,
    'name' => $f,
);

$subscriber = $ML_Subscribers->setId( LIST_ID )->setAutoresponders(false)->add( $subscriber );
```

Where you would replace `API_KEY` with the provided MailerLite API key, and `LIST_ID` with the ID of the list that you wish to add the subscriber to.

Otherwise if you weren't using their SDK you would need to make a `POST` to their endpoint: POST https://app.mailerlite.com/api/v1/subscribers/{list_id}/. You would also be required to construct the proper data object to be sent over containing `your API Key`, `an Email` and the `id of the subscriber list`.

You can read further about this in [the MailerLite Documentation](https://docs.mailerlite.com/pages/subscribers#post)

Comment: When I user this exact same code, it's not subscribing. I was wondering, should I put the API_KEY and LIST_ID between ' ' or just entering it without them?

Comment: @SenneVandenputte They should be sent over as strings as far as I can tell, I've never personally used the API, but the docs were insightful.

Comment: Strange, it's not working.. I have a php and ajax script that puts them in the database and sends them an email about their registration. Then I've put the MailerLite code behind it and end with `echo "signup_success"` which shows that the subscribtion is successful. Now the user is subscribed but the signup success message is not triggered since the MailerLite script is not working..

Comment: @SenneVandenputte I think that the issue lay elsewhere. Check logs and what have you. Otherwise, try to construct it manually like I indicated in my last paragraph.

Comment: Without the MailerLite script, everything is working just fine so it has something to do with that script but I can't find what. I don't have any experience with API's and only basic knowledge of PHP etc. Would it be possible to give me an example of how I could do it?  The MailerLite calls are basic so I don't think it will be very complicated, but as I said, I really don't have much knowledge about it..

Comment: [David Walsh has a great writeup](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) about making `CURL POST Requests`. That will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely look into it. Before using MailerLite I used Mailchimp. I had a script that used curl to subscribe members to Mailchimp and that was working perfectly. I'll see if I can just adapt that script to work with MailerLite. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I managed to do it by just adapting the script I had with Mailchimp!